# Why does the "Unable to Sync" pop-up window appear even though I have Steam Cloud Synchronization disabled?

Tags: steam, steam-cloud, resident-evil-4-2005

Just a few days ago I started noticing this pop-up while playing Resident Evil 4 on Steam:
[image]

I am not sure why this started happening only recently, as I have not made any changes in my settings, and as you can see, I don't use Cloud Sync at all:

[image]

Could someone please tell me how to disable this annoyance? It seems to only happen when my game crashes.

Running Steam Version:

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I have this frequently, and had it often with The Witcher 3. I assume it has to do with connectivity problems, and I *think* certain saves are uploaded to specific servers that time out before a connection is made, in which case Steam might try connecting later.

Comment: In any case, this seems a duplicate of the following question: [How to fix "Steam unable to sync" error?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/121286/how-to-fix-steam-unable-to-sync-error)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is not a duplicate though, as the other poster is asking how to enable syncing. I am trying to find out why my game is giving me sync alerts when I have it turned off.

Comment: And the solution from the suggested dupe (nuke the local saves and allow them to be repopulated by the cloud) would be catastrophic in this situation!

Comment: Hi, just wondering if your last comment was sarcastic? I am open to all ideas, but I kind of want to understand why its happening. Thanks!

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Roddy means the suggested solution would delete all your progress (local save which is not synced replaced by the contents of the Steam cloud, which you said you didn't sync to, so that would probably be the same as a full reset). tl;dr: Roddy agrees with you :)

Comment: @MiG understood.